# regex match one line not two new line

Tags: regex, node.js

Hello I'm trying to get text from html using a regex

`([a-zA-Z0-9\:\[\]\40\.\'\,\?\"\&\(\/\)\-\“\”\’\@]){600,} // let's say the example is more than 600 letters`

The problem is

I want to add `\n` two my regex but a max two newline eg

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dictum metus ipsum, ut hendrerit sem consectetur quis.   
\n
Nunc tincidunt mi nisl, in lobortis diam pulvinar vel. Nulla at tempus enim, sit amet viverra nisl.
\n
Nunc tincidunt mi nisl, in lobortis diam pulvinar vel. Nulla at tempus enim, sit amet viverra nisl.
\n
\n
Not this
```

It will only match the first 3 line so I get something like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dictum metus ipsum, ut hendrerit sem consectetur quis.   
\n (ok)
Nunc tincidunt mi nisl, in lobortis diam pulvinar vel. Nulla at tempus enim, sit amet viverra nisl.
\n (ok still one)
.....
\n (ok still one)
\n (ups its more than one then stop a group)
```

The result will be

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dictum metus ipsum, ut hendrerit sem consectetur quis.   

Nunc tincidunt mi nisl, in lobortis diam pulvinar vel. Nulla at tempus enim, sit amet viverra nisl.

Nunc tincidunt mi nisl, in lobortis diam pulvinar vel. Nulla at tempus enim, sit amet viverra nisl.
```

Comment: the input is the first one jerry

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://regex101.com/r/cO5vZ4 ?

Comment: jerry yeah but the opposite, matching the text and one line, but stop if we meet a two line.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing exactly still, but maybe something like [that](http://regex101.com/r/xR2mN1).

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9: \[\].',?"&(/)“”’@-]{600,}\n\n(?!\n)
```

matches 600 or more of your allowed characters, plus two newlines only if no additional newline can be found after that match.

Comment: Will work nice too. The only problem would be if the pattern don't finish with two newlines. Not sure if this matter thought.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be.

```
    ([a-zA-Z0-9\:\[\]\40\.\'\,\?\"\&\(\/\)\-\“\”\’\@]\n?){600,}
```

Two things:

- The newlines will not be counted in the character limit (600 in your case)
- This will not work in your example because it has less than 600 characters (it has about 330).